# Solution for silent-kiosk print on CefSharp?

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I want to print my web page silently ( to default printer) with "window.print()" command on CefSharp. CefSharp handles the documents and print very good but i can't prevent printer dialog screen.   Is there any option or method to prevent printerdialog ?

DotNetBrowser provides silent print functionality but it has page scrolling problem and it is slower than ChefSharp.

Thanks

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1821

Comment: @amaitland there is no way for silent printing except printtopdf on CefSharp as you said.  https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/886#issuecomment-138704416

Comment: by the way; dotnetbrowser provides silent printing with default printer but its slower than ChefSharp also it has license cost.

Comment: You can discuss the feature request at http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=14196 it needs to be implemented in `CEF`. `CefSharp` is just a wrapper.