# Cannot print from a website provided Print link using CefSharp

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

A webpage has links to start a print job on it. Clicking the link initiates a new popup window and then immediately the print dialog is shown. The popup window is not rendered and if I click print, then a blank page is printed. It appears that the print dialog is blocking the popup from rendering the page first. If I cancel the print dialog the popup renders properly but now there is no print dialog.

The behavior is the same when using the CefSharp Winforms example.

Is this something I need to deal with? Can I dismiss the print dialog, let the page render and then call the dialog again?

The TargetURL of the popup is about:blank which does not give me much to go on that it is a print action. How does CefSharp tell you it has been asked to print something?

For people landing here from Google printing seems to be rather limited in CEF still and thus in CefSharp. See [General Usage Printing](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#printing) and [Silently Printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267466/how-to-print-silently-in-cefsharp) and also [Kiosk Printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40115552/solution-for-silent-kiosk-print-on-cefsharp) for example.

Also there is a [PrintToPDF](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/55.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserHost_PrintToPdf.htm) which I have not tried yet.

Looking at how Google Chrome does this it appears it renders the page to a PDF file and then shows this file in a popup/new tab. Of course they have then built their own silent printing as the next step.

**Edit**
**Using cef_binary_3.3683.1920.g9f41a27_windows64_client with**

1. No extra arguments
2. clicking exactly the same link
3. a popup window appears
4. the print window appears
5. the popup window navigates to display preview of what is to be printed
6. Print can be clicked to print the information viewed in the popup

**Using CEFSharp Master WinForms version**

1. No extra arguments (other than set by the example at startup)
2. clicking exactly the same link
3. a popup window appears
4. the print window appears
5. the popup window appears blocked and is blank.
6. Print can be clicked and it prints a beautiful white blank page.
7. AFTER print window closes the popup window navigates to the information to be printed.

Comment: Your better off asking at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewforum.php?f=6 Likely `CEF` would need to be modified

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a question for CEF. You see before googling "CefSharp ...." leads me to many questions which fairly regularly (and understandably) lead to a referal to CEF. When I click the same link in the CEFClient the popup window is allowed to navigate and thus the print output is not blank. So I am currently stuck with CefSharp canNOT and CEF Client can.

Comment: What command line args did you use for testing cefclient? Your question should include any background research you have performed, this is vital information, why isn't included in your question?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Have updated the question. Once the question is to your liking you might consider removing the -1

Comment: You need to test cefclient with the args listed in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#cefsharp-vs-chromium-embedded-frameworkcef

Comment: Also do you have an example link to be used for testing?